# How to disable DHCP or put manually IP's without lose Internet connection

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet, ipv4

I have a problem with the router ASUS DSL-N16. Actually I want to pre-assign and IP to each device I have using the MAC of each device, no problem with this step. Now I put the IPv4, DNS and submask manually on each device and just after that I lose the Internet connection in the mentionned device. I want to apply those steps with wired and Wifi Connections.

Can someone explain me how to do these steps correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an impression you're doing two contradictory things. MAC-based IP assignment in router's config works only with DHCP enabled. If you have static IP configuration on all devices DHCP won't be used and those assignments will effectively be unused. Loss of Internet connectivity suggests that you're either misconfiguring IP or DNS servers.

Comment: Aside from doing two contradictory things (reserving in DHCP and manual setup), when you did the manual setup part, did you set a gateway address too (router IP)? Apart from misconfiguring IP/DNS as @gronostaj says, that might another reason why you lose internet connectivity.

Comment: Yes I put the router IP as gateway adress. This is the reason I don't understand why I lose the connection.